# What is required to use LODSB in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, segments

What is the minimum set of steps required to use LODSB to load a relative address to a string in my code?

I have the following test program that I'm using PXE to boot. I boot it two ways: via pxelinux.0 and directly. If I boot it directly, my program prints both strings. If I boot via pxelinux.0, it only prints the first string.

Why?

> **Answer:**  The code is fine, the initial address math is wrong. See below.

Working technique (for both):

- Set the direction flag to increment, `cld`
- Set `ds` to `cs`
- Put the address (from start) of string in `si`
- Add the starting offset to `si`

Non-working technique (just for pxelinux):

- Calculate a new segment address based on `(((cs << 4) + offset) >> 4)`
- Set `ds` to that. (either A000 or 07C0)

[*text here to fix bug in markdown*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/bug-code-blocks-after-numbered-or-bulleted-lists-completely-disappear)

```
// Note: If you try this code, don't forget to set 
//       the "#if 0" below appropriately!

    .text
    .globl  start, _start

start:  
_start: 
_start1:    

    .code16

    jmp real_start

    . = _start1 + 0x1fe
    .byte 0x55, 0xAA

    // Next sector
    . = _start1 + 0x200

    jmp real_start

test1_str:
    .asciz  "\r\nTest: 9020:fe00"
test2_str:
    .asciz  "\r\nTest: a000:0000"

real_start:

    cld         // Make sure %si gets incremented.

#if 0
    // When loaded by pxelinux, we're here:
    // 9020:fe00 ==> a000:0000

    // This works.
    movw    $0x9020, %bx
    movw    %bx, %ds
    movw    $(test1_str - _start1), %si
    addw    $0xfe00, %si
    call    print_message

    // This does not.
    movw    $0xA000, %bx
    movw    %bx, %ds
    movw    $(test2_str - _start1), %si
    call    print_message
#else
    // If we are loaded directly without pxelinux, we're here:
    // 0000:7c00 ==> 07c0:0000

    // This works.
    movw    $0x0000, %bx
    movw    %bx, %ds
    movw    $(test1_str - _start1), %si
    addw    $0x7c00, %si
    call    print_message

    // This does, too.
    movw    $0x07c0, %bx
    movw    %bx, %ds
    movw    $(test2_str - _start1), %si
    call    print_message
#endif

    // Hang the computer
    sti
1:
    jmp 1b


// Prints string DS:SI (modifies AX BX SI)
print_message:
    pushw   %ax
    jmp 2f
3:
    movb    $0x0e, %ah  /* print char in AL */
    int $0x10       /* via TTY mode */
2:  
    lodsb   (%si), %al  /* get token */
    cmpb    $0, %al     /* end of string? */
    jne 3b
    popw    %ax
    ret

.balign 0x200
```

Here's the compilation:

```
/usr/bin/ccache gcc -Os -fno-stack-protector -fno-builtin -nostdinc  -DSUPPORT_SERIAL=1 -DSUPPORT_HERCULES=1 -DSUPPORT_GRAPHICS=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Wall -ggdb3 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wunused -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -falign-functions=1 -Wundef -g -c -o ds_teststart_exec-ds_teststart.o ds_test.S
/usr/bin/ccache gcc  -g   -o ds_teststart.exec -nostdlib -Wl,-N -Wl,-Ttext -Wl,8000 ds_teststart_exec-ds_teststart.o  
objcopy -O binary ds_teststart.exec ds_teststart
```

Comment: If the problem turns out to be something else entirely, I'll re-word the whole question for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First problem:**

9020:FE00 ==> 9000:0000 and not A000:0000
I was using some code from grldrstart.S that does that calculation. There's a bug in the grldrstart.S routine. It takes the FE00 offset and shifts it right 4 bits, but it does it without preserving the sign; FE00 is a negative number. So instead of:

```
shrw   $4, %bx
```

it should have been

```
sarw   $4, %bx   // Preserves sign!!
```

90200 + FE00 = 90200 - 200 = 90000

**Question Answer:**

In order to use LODSB, you must:

- set `ds` properly (and use correct math)
- set the direction flag correctly, using `cld` or `std` for increment and decrement
- set `si` to the offset to your source buffer.
- the effective address read will be `(ds << 4) + si`

Answer (score 0):

To set ds -->

push cs

pop  ds

Comment: @smiffy: but I want to calculate a new segment address so that I don't have to add the original offset to every ds:si based instruction. So a string at offset 0x40 in my program can be either `(0000 << 4) + 7c00 + 40` or `(07c0 << 4) + 40`